# Setting Listeners programmatically to an array of CheckBoxes

Tags: java, android, arrays, listener

So far, I've encountered the issue "variable x is accessed within inner class,needs to be declared final. I am able to initialize the CheckBox's but I am unable to set a listener to them after initialization in the loop. Below is my code so far.

```
for(int i=0;i<checkBox_fiber_ID.length;i++){
            int temp=getResources().getIdentifier(checkBox_fiber_ID[i],"id",getPackageName());
            checkBoxes_fiber[i]=findViewById(temp);
            checkBoxes_fiber[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(checkBoxes_fiber[i].isChecked()){
                        //do something
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: how are the checkboxes created? It seems to  be some kind of dynamic setup, in which case using a RecyclerView to dynamically setup the checkboxes and the listeners might be a better way to go. atleast thats what i did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take **final String[] x={"defaultvalue Emptry"}**

Then after inside onclick Listener set value of x using below code.

x[0]="new value"

and use this value in different function.

as per your code it look likes blow:

```
final String x[] ={""}
for(int i=0;i<checkBox_fiber_ID.length;i++){
        int temp=getResources().getIdentifier(checkBox_fiber_ID[i],"id",getPackageName());
        checkBoxes_fiber[i]=findViewById(temp);
        checkBoxes_fiber[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(checkBoxes_fiber[i].isChecked()){
                   x[0]=checkBoxes_fiber[i].getvalue==> value name
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**Outside function get value of x using**

```
String name=x[0]
```

Comment: the `i` variable is not a final variable, is it possible to use  the `i` in an inner class?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create separate class of listener

```
 private View.OnClickListener mCheckboxListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if(((CheckBox)view).isChecked())
        {
        int checkBoxId = (int)v.getTag();  //You can get Id for specific checkbox
        //do other stuff with checkBoxId
       }
   }
};
```

And set Id to each checkbox like

```
for(int i=0;i<checkBox_fiber_ID.length;i++){
            int temp=getResources().getIdentifier(checkBox_fiber_ID[i],"id",getPackageName());
            checkBoxes_fiber[i]=findViewById(temp);
            checkBoxes.setTag(i); //set check box id as tag for later usage
            checkBoxes_fiber[i].setOnClickListener(mCheckboxListener);
        }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the tag variable. How can it be used to check whether or not the checkbox is checked? Sorry, I'm quite new to android.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to do something base on the checkbox IDs. You can set a `tag` for a checkBox and get back the `tag` in future. Also, the `view` object in method `void onClick(View view)` is now an CheckBox. Just change a little in your code:

```
for(int i=0;i<checkBox_fiber_ID.length;i++){
            int temp=getResources().getIdentifier(checkBox_fiber_ID[i],"id",getPackageName());
            checkBoxes_fiber[i]=findViewById(temp);
            checkBoxes_fiber[i].setTag(i); //mark the check box id for later usage
            checkBoxes_fiber[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(((CheckBox)view).isChecked()){
                        int checkBoxId = (int)view.getTag();
                        doSomething(checkBoxId);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
}
```

And write a new method for business code:

```
public void doSomething(int no){
    if(no==1){
       //do something
    }
    else if(no==2){
       //do something
    }
    //...
}
```